# Upgrading WordPress broke my site

Tags: html, wordpress, permalinks

I upgraded my website to wordpress 3.4 and it's caused an enormous amount of damage to my site. Half of my posts weren't accessible on the site and 404d, and pages 3 and 4 of my posts on my website 404d as well.

I backed up before upgrading (thank god I had a gut feeling there'd be headaches) using PressBackup. After restoring, I managed to finally be able see my other posts that were missing before, but there's a still a problem. Pages 3 and 4 still don't work ie http://www.winvenue.com/page/3/. Interestingly all the posts that disappeared were from page 3 and page 4.

I'm not sure why I got all these issues, and it's really annoying because this is an active website will hundreds of readers. I'd really like the get this fixed, any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the mean time, try [**this**](http://pressbackup.com/contactus/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing about your specific setup, there's some general things you can try.

I'd check the database to see if the posts are really there. If they are, see if the ones that show are any different for the ones that aren't shown.

Then disable all plugins etc to see if any of those can cause problems with the new version. If it works without plugins, turn them on one by one to see which one(s) cause problems.

Comment: The posts were restored with the database restore. The problem now is that pages http://www.winvenue.com/page/3/ and 4 don't work. Only the first 2.

I've been at this for a while and I'm pretty sure I might have found something that might have to do with this. The title (browser tab title) on the first two pagination links show 1/2 and 2/2. Prior to updating when I clicked on page 3 it would show 3/2 and 4/2 appropriately. It's like something somewhere is not recognizing the amount of pages on the website...

Comment: Could you insert the paging data to the templates in hidden divs to test this theory? If the paging is wrong, it should be wrong in the database data. If so, it might be easiest to fix it manually to the database. I assume you don't have a separate development version, as then you probably wouldn't have this problem...

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure how to do what you're asking. I don't have a development version unfortunately, definitely something I'm going to have to look into.

Comment: Is there any way I could provide you with my info and you can perhaps take a look? I'm even willing to pay at this point... This has been one of most stressful nights for me in a while, I just want this fixed :(

Comment: A quick test, seemed like it can't find any page after 2, or possibly any posts before 4th of june? I don't have the time to investigate deeper into this now, but if you're willing to pay you might try sites like https://www.elance.com/r/contractors/q-wordpress/ to find somebody willing to do the job? It shouldn't take  more than a couple of hours (unless the problems go way deeper than it seems).

Answer (score 0):

Restoring from backup probably dosen't include the .htaccess file which responsible on the permalinks.

Try and regenerate your .htaccess file using settings->permalinks->save or manually

Comment: PressBackup backed up the htaccess, and I've tried restoring it. I've also tried saving and changing every permalink option, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following field on Settings->Reading (wp-admin/options-reading.php)

> Blog pages show at most [5] posts

It could be that your pagination thinks there are 2 posts per page when there are actually 4 (for example) which would cause this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced the same issue when upgrading, seems like others as well, when I did a search on Google. Try searching for a draft version of the missing pages, usually WordPress will backup automatically while your typing. Also try the Trash folder, you never know. You may also need to possibly revert back to an older backup file, which may contain the missing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins maybe change your permalink rewrite rules. So, try to deactivate your plugin, all of them. Then reset your permalinks: Setting > permalinks, don't change anything but saving it. Check your site, if it's normal, then it must be one of the plugins.

If it doesn't work, before reactivating the plugins, change to default theme (twenty eleven) andd see if it works with it.

For all I can see, this kind of problems most often come from misconfigured internal rewrite rules.

EDIT: Have you tried to not use pagination?

You can also try to debug by deactivate the canonical redirection by adding:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canoncial ')
```

on your functions.php. This will disable the internal URL redirection.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your permalinks settings